# How to get Firefox version number?

Tags: firefox, version, autoit

Trying to get Firefox version number, why is the line not copied from the dll file?

```
#RequireAdmin
$DLL = DllOpen("xul.dll")
$st = FileReadLine('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\xul.dll', 175055);   
$st2 = StringLeft($st, 80)
$st3 = StringRight($st2, 12);
FileWriteLine('1.txt', $st3)
DllClose($DLL)
```

Do I need to convert to UTF-8?

Comment: Did you try to firstly read line and after that `DllOpen`. I think DllOpen is locking the file somehow.

Comment: "*Why is the line not copied from the dll file?*" DLL files do not contain lines. Explain what you're trying to achieve by attempting to read binary files as text instead.

Comment: I need the number 62.0.2.

Comment: Are you trying to read Firefox' version number?

Comment: Yes.In that file, besides the version, there are other parameters.

Answer (score -1):

> "*Trying to get Firefox version number* …"

Using cmdline output:

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <StringConstants.au3>

Global Const $g_sVersion = _FirefoxGetVersion('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
ConsoleWrite($g_sVersion & @CRLF)

Func _FirefoxGetVersion(Const $sPath)
    Local Const $sRgx = '([\d\.]+)', _
                $sCmd = StringFormat('%s /c "%s" -v | more', @ComSpec, $sPath)
    Local Const $iPID = Run($sCmd, '', @SW_HIDE, $STDOUT_CHILD)

    If Not $iPID Then Return ''

    ProcessWaitClose($iPID)

    Local Const $sStd = StdoutRead($iPID)
    Local Const $aRes = StringRegExp($sStd, $sRgx, $STR_REGEXPARRAYMATCH)

    StdioClose($iPID)

    Return $aRes[0]
EndFunc
```